# Using Count on a Join - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have two tables, one with a group of teams and info about them. The other table has info about games they have played. I wish to count how many games a specific team has played.

I've got team_number, team_name on one table named team. I've got played_team on the other table named played, which is a foreign key to team_number.

How  can I code a join to count the number of occurrences of  played_team and join it with team_number and team_name?

I am using MYSQL 5.1, I hope this makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: More info needed about the structure and contents of the second table, containing the played_team field.

Comment: What other info is needed? I just wish to join team.team_number and team.team_name to played.played_team and count the separate occurrences of played_team.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Does `played_team` refer to a "team B" that "team A" played (and you are trying to count the number of times team A played)? Or instead, does `played_team` merely serve as a flag that the team participated in one game?

Comment: @user1745447 It's also advised that you show [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: @RobertB 'Or instead, does played_team merely serve as a flag that the team participated in one game?' - this is the correct option. It's very simple, I just want it to keep count of how many games each team have played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
select teams.`team_name`, count(matches.`played_team`) 
from teams 
join matches on teams.`team_number` = matches.`played_team` 
group by teams.`team_name`
```

Here are the tables I used:

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `team_number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `team_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`team_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `teams` (`team_number`, `team_name`)
VALUES
    (1,'a'),
    (2,'b'),
    (3,'c'),
    (4,'d');

CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `played_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_title` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `played_team` (`played_team`),
  CONSTRAINT `matches_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`played_team`) REFERENCES `teams` (`team_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `matches` (`played_team`, `id`, `match_title`)
VALUES
    (1,1,'match_a'),
    (1,2,'match_b'),
    (3,3,'match_c'),
    (4,4,'match_d');
```

And here are the results of the query:

```
team_name    count(matches.`played_team`)  
a            2  
c            1  
d            1
```

Comment: this is a great answer, thanks! now how could I add a where clause so that it only counts games that are played past 2011-01-01?

Comment: matches.date holds info on the date of the game

Comment: That depends on what kind of field matches.date is. Is it a UNIX timestamp? If it is, then it would be 'where matches.date > 1293840000'.